# Aviarc: access logged in user during error screens

Tags: aviarc

When trying to create different looking global error screen for an application, is it possible to add the logged in user to the error screen?

The authentication dataset seems to be blank inside the system/error.xml scope, even if you were logged in when the error occurred.

Is there another way to access the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the system/error.xml workflow to catch errors, the authentication dataset is not available.

Instead, enclosing most of the start workflow with a

```
<with-error-workflow name="error.xml">
      <!-- main app start goes here -->
</with-error-workflow>
```

to catch errors will provide the authentication dataset.